# Java Swing Layered pane is not showing itself or its content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to do layers via LayeredPanes. First I create new label and insert into it image. Then I want to create layeredPane, which contain label. This layeredPane is then inserted into panel with GridLayout. Code below should add into this grid 2 images, but it adds only the C JLabel, but not the layeredPane. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help

```
JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
layeredPane.setName("P" + i*size+j);

JLabel c;
c = new JLabel(images[0]);

c.setName("L" + i*size+j);
c.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
c.setVisible(true);

layeredPane.add(c, layeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
layeredPane.setVisible(true);

jPanel1.add(c);
jPanel1.add(layeredPane);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
layeredPane.add(c, layeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
layeredPane.setVisible(true);

jPanel1.add(c);
```

The above line removes c from layeredPane and adds it to jPanel1. LayeredPane now has no subcomponents in it.

```
jPanel1.add(layeredPane);
```